# Notice: Undefined index: SESS_NAME in student_vote.php on line 9

Tags: php

```
   <?php
    include "connection.php";

     if(!isset($_SESSION)) 
        { 
            session_start(); 
        } 
    $cand1  = $_POST['cand1'];

    $cand2  = $_POST['vice1'];





    $sess   =  $_SESSION['SESS_NAME'];




    if(!$cand1){
    $error="<center><h4><font color='#FF0000'>Please fill empty fields</h4></center></font>";
    include"student.php";
    exit();
    }



        $cand1 = addslashes($cand1);


        $cand1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$cand1);







    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM student WHERE username="'.$_SESSION['SESS_NAME'].'" AND status="VOTED"';





    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

                if (mysqli_num_rows($result)==1){

            $msg="<center><h4><font color='#FF0000'>You have already been voted, No need to vote again</h4></center></font>";
            include 'student.php';
            exit(); 
                }

                else{

                 $sql = 'UPDATE candidate SET votecount = votecount + 1 WHERE cand_id = "'.$_POST['cand1'].'" OR cand_id = "'.$_POST['vice1'].'"';






                $sql2 = 'UPDATE student SET status="VOTED" WHERE username="'.$_SESSION['SESS_NAME'].'"';


                $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                $result2 = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);

        if(!$result && !$result2){
        die("Error on mysql query".mysqli_error());
        }
        else{
        $msg="<center><h4><font color='#FF0000'>Congratulation, you have made your vote.</h4></center></font>";
        include 'student.php';
        exit();
        }
                }


    ?>
```

the  errors are  at code including
      $sess= $_SESSION['SESS_NAME']; and at username="'.$_SESSION['SESS_NAME'].'"
i have tried every possibility so can you check my code?
mainly the error is undefined index at $session[session_name]?

Comment: You are trying to access a variable in `$_SESSION` that doesn't exist. Do you set the `$_SESSION['SESSION_NAME']` in the code that leads to `student_vote.php`? You can read about how to set the session in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: Yeah it possibly is

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the session `'SESS_NAME'` is getting set? In the code above you are only trying to access its value. Undefined index is the error thrown when there is no session with that name.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like to me you haven't declared the variable $_SESSION['SESS_NAME']. Try doing the following

```
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

This will show you all the defined variables in the session, if SESS_NAME isn't there then it hasn't been defined. Maybe you have failed to define it somewhere else?